# PropertyException after wildfly update: property CharacterEscapeHandler must be an instance of type CharacterEscapeHandler

Tags: java, jaxb, wildfly

Some time ago I implemented a [CustomCharacterEscapeHandler](http://www.tutego.de/blog/javainsel/2019/11/snippet-jaxb-and-cdata-contenthandler-with-characterescapehandler/) and it worked fine up-to Wildfly-18.0.1. Now when updating to Wildfly 19 or higher I get the following exception:

```
javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: property "com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler" must be an instance of type com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.CharacterEscapeHandler, not my.package.CustomCharacterEscapeHandler
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.setProperty(MarshallerImpl.java:489)
```

But my CustomCharacterEscapeHandler implements exactly the mentioned interface!

The maven `pom.xml` looks like this:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

I researched a lot and did try out all the solutions I could find ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50473101/jaxb-wont-accept-customescapehandler), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744999/error-while-converting-object-to-xml-using-jaxb-with-custom-character-escape-han/54745591), [3](https://groups.google.com/g/jbpm-development/c/UHZL3UKXxzs?pli=1), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28696160/error-while-serializing-timestamp-element-occured-while-performing-canonicalizat), [5](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-16100)) but many questions remain unanswered ([6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48108903/javax-xml-bind-propertyexception-on-docx4j-bundle-when-loading-document),[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623139/karaf-servicemix-weird-instanceof-behaviour),[8](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/263862),[9](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9353),[10](https://cmsdk.com/java/jaxb-marshall--property-characterescapehandler-must-be-a-instance-of-type-com-sun-xml-bind-marshaller-characterescapehandler.html)) and the things mentioned did not work. So I tried:

- added jaxb.properties containing `javax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`
- updated to newer JAXB Versions
- added a startup property `-Djavax.xml.bind.context.factory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`
- added the EscapHandler as inline code `jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(), (CharacterEscapeHandler) (chars, start, length, b, writer) -> ... );`
- tried adding exclusion(s) in the `jboss-deployment-structure` (com.sun.xml.bind, javax.xml.bind.api,...) and also tried the opposite to add them as dependencies

**However nothing worked so far. Any ideas how to fix this?**

Comment: Might be a classloading problem, one option that could work is to set all jaxb dependencies as provided

Comment: That is not possible since the deployment package is deployed on many different JEE application servers Wildfly, jboss, websphere, weblogic ...) and sometimes different versions of a server. The solution can only be to exclude the wildfly provided packages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found **two** working solutions:

1. Adding a startup property to the wildfly startscript `-Djavax.xml.bind.JAXBContextFactory=com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory`
2. Aligning the JAXB libraries of my application with the wildfly JAXB libs

**Background and some details for the 2nd solution:**

The JAXB used in wildfly 19 has been updated (cp. [1](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBEAP-18292),[2](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-16100)).
Since nothing worked I started debugging it. First the working version on wildfly 18 and then the non working version. The corresponding code is :

```
 MarshallerImpl.java:
 ...
 if( ENCODING_HANDLER.equals(name) || ENCODING_HANDLER2.equals(name)) {
            if(!(value instanceof CharacterEscapeHandler)) //<- fails here!
                throw new PropertyException(
                    Messages.MUST_BE_X.format(
                            name,
                            CharacterEscapeHandler.class.getName(),
                            value.getClass().getName() ) );
            escapeHandler = (CharacterEscapeHandler)value;
            return;
        }
```

But for the non working version the debugger jumped into an area which was obviously incorrect thus I knew that a different version of JAXB was used.
So I did the following:

1. I checked what jaxb version is bundled with wildfly. `WILDFLY_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/com/sun/xml/bind/main`
2. I used the exact same versions in my `pom.xml` file

**=> Then it was working!**

What I don't understand is that I tried excluding the wildfly-packaged-jaxb but that didn't help. So this will remain a mystery why my exclusion of JAXB via the jboss-deployment-structure? didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this adding the following `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`  to the application (in `WEB-INF` folder):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="webservices" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javax.xml.bind.api" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```